# STM32 Interrupt Priority

Tags: stm32, interrupt, priority-queue, uart, spi

When using Rx interrupt, I transmit the data to another place via SPI during the interrupt. However, while this process occurs when there is a delay in the main loop, the process does not occur when there is no delay in the main loop.

What would be the reason?

Kind regards

```
void HAL_UARTEx_RxEventCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint16_t Size){
    HAL_UARTEx_ReceiveToIdle_IT(&huart3, RxBuffer,RxBufferSize);
    size1=Size;
         send(1,RxBuffer,size1);

}

  while (1)
  {
 if(getSn_SR(1)==SOCK_ESTABLISHED){
 if((size = getSn_RX_RSR(1)) > 0){ 
    recv(1, TxBuffer, size);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_1,GPIO_PIN_SET);
     HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(&huart3, TxBuffer,size);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_1,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    size=0;}}
//  HAL_Delay(100);  
  }
```

When it enters the interface, I want it to return to the main loop without doing the operation there and I want to give priority to that side.

Comment: You (and we) might understand your code better if it was formatted properly. But even then, you probably haven't give us nearly enough information to guess what is going on here.

Comment: Do not do this in the interrupt callbacks. They have to be as simple and fast as possible.

Comment: If you don't have a delay, your while(1) executes non-stop all the time. Including recv function, whatever that does, as well as HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA. Without delay, it's called again and again and again all the time, the next call happens before the current DMA transmittion is over (because UART us much slower than CPU or RAM). Pretty sure something goes wrong there when you tell it to do DMA trasfer while the last DMA transfer isn't finished yet.